# error in org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

Message `internal error`

Exception stacktrace

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 16: project-aware://Spring form demo/org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3186)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathUriResolver.getTargetNamespace(ProjectClasspathUriResolver.java:156)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathUriResolver.init(ProjectClasspathUriResolver.java:111)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathUriResolver.<init>(ProjectClasspathUriResolver.java:52)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver$1.call(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:167)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver$1.call(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.getProjectResolver(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.resolve(ProjectClasspathExtensibleUriResolver.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver.internal.ExtensibleURIResolver.resolve(ExtensibleURIResolver.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.ValidatorHelper$MyContentHandler.startElement(ValidatorHelper.java:286)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.ValidatorHelper.computeValidationInformation(ValidatorHelper.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.XMLValidator.validate(XMLValidator.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator.validate(Validator.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator.validate(Validator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validate(AbstractNestedValidator.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validateInJob(AbstractNestedValidator.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.validation.DelegatingSourceValidator.validate(DelegatingSourceValidator.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ReconcileStepForValidator.validate(ReconcileStepForValidator.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ReconcileStepForValidator.reconcileModel(ReconcileStepForValidator.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconcileStep.reconcile(AbstractReconcileStep.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ValidatorStrategy.reconcile(ValidatorStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.DocumentRegionProcessor.process(DocumentRegionProcessor.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor.process(StructuredRegionProcessor.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.DirtyRegionProcessor$BackgroundThread.run(DirtyRegionProcessor.java:691)
```

Session Data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

whenever I open my xml file I encounter through following error

`Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/security/web/util/AntPathRequestMatcher'. See Error Log for more detail`

I have installed eclipse neon with jdk1.8 on it in windows xp and It was working fine untill I made more then one configuration files in eclipse and now I am getting error in every xml file

How to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an illegal character in your URI.

Try replacing the spaces in your URI with "%20", like so:

`...//Spring%20form%20demo/org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd`

Or, try moving your XSD to a directory that does not contain any spaces in its path.

Comment: %20 represents `space` in uri